# parsing url into Swift2 Class property

Tags: json, swift2, xcode7

I'm fetching data from a Web Api json result into my IOS App.

Everything Ok until I try to parse a field with a Url.

It gives an error no matter which Url I'm passing.

Error message: Thread 3:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

```
import Foundation

class DuiDownload {
var nom:String = ""
var features:String = ""
var thumbnailUrl:String = ""
var fileUrl:String = ""

class func fetch(fromTarget target:DuiGuidNom, completion:(retval:[DuiDownload]?, error:NSError?) -> Void) -> Void {
    let sUrl:String = apiUrl("api/Downloads")

    let params:[String:AnyObject] = ["guid" : target.guid]
    apiRequest(sUrl,params: params,callback: { (data: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        guard error == nil else {
            completion(retval: nil, error: error)
            return
        }
        guard data != nil else {
            completion(retval: nil, error: error)
            return
        }

        guard let jsonResults = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String : AnyObject]] else {
            completion(retval: nil, error: NSError(domain: "somedomain", code: 123, userInfo: ["Error reason":"invalid Json"]))
            return
        }

        var retval:[DuiDownload]=[]

        for item in jsonResults! {
            let duiDownload = DuiDownload()
            duiDownload.nom = item["Nom"] as! String
            duiDownload.features = item["Features"] as! String
            duiDownload.thumbnailUrl = item["ThumbnailUrl"] as! String
            duiDownload.fileUrl = item["FileUrl"] as! String
            retval.append(duiDownload)

        }

        completion(retval: retval, error: nil)
        return
    })
}

}
```

Comment: which line through this error

Comment: duiDownload.thumbnailUrl = item["ThumbnailUrl"] as! String

Comment: item contents as follows:▿ 4 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "Nom"
    - .1 : Impost IVTM 2012
  ▿ [1] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "ThumnailUrl"
    - .1 : http://www.matiasmasso.es/img/56/3877756864386b344c4e336e4f4239303233394a52673d3d
  ▿ [2] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "Features"
    - .1 : 373 Kb Pdf 2 pags. 208x292 mm  29/03/12 13:47
  ▿ [3] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "FileUrl"
    - .1 : http://www.matiasmasso.es/doc/9/3877756864386b344c4e336e4f4239303233394a52673d3d

Comment: the error says: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, but  there is a properly formatted url string in the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ashemed. ThumbnailUrl was misspelled. Everything is working Ok now